# How many number of inapp product can be sell on single Android/iOS app?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Can we sell 100 or more inapp purchase product on single Android or iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit for the number of in app purchase items on play store but
it is powered by google wallet and Google Wallet has a daily spending limit of $1,000. So an user will not be able to purchase more than $1000 from your app per day. That's the only limit I believe. But for iOS, the limit is probably 10,000 in app products.